# Python show corresponding profile upon hovering/clicking over a grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2D array `value_1` which depends on `lon`(longitude) and `lat`(latitude).
Now, I can use `pcolormesh` to plot the value on one figure.

But, I have another 3D array `value_2` which depends on `lon`, `lat` and `pressure` (levels of pressure).

If I want to show the profile (depends on `value_2` and `pressure`) and coordinate like this: `(-120,20)` when the mouse hover or click on one grid(lon,lat), how could I make it?

Here's the example of plotting `pseudocolor plot` and `profile plot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# coordination
lon = np.arange(-120,-110,1)
lat = np.arange(20,30,1)

# shape of value_1: (lon,lat)
# pseudocolor plot

value_1 = np.random.rand(9,9)
pressure = np.arange(1110,500,-100)
lon,lat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
plt.pcolormesh(lon,lat,value_1)

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()

# shape of value_2: (lon,lat,pressure)
# profile plot
# Used to plot profile when mouse hovers on one grid

value_2 = np.random.rand(9,9,pressure.shape[0])
```

[image: pseudocolor]
[image: profile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there a more efficient way to get the right indices when hovering over the pcolormesh, but this does the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs
from math import floor

# coordination
lon = np.arange(-120, -110, 1)
lat = np.arange(20, 30, 1)

# shape of value_1: (lon,lat)
# pseudocolor plot
value_1 = np.random.rand(9, 9)
pressure = np.arange(1110, 500, -100)
mlon, mlat = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

# shape of value_2: (lon,lat,pressure)
# profile plot
# Used to plot profile when mouse hovers on one grid
value_2 = np.random.rand(9, 9, pressure.shape[0])

# global variables to keep track of which values
# are currently plotted in ax2
current_lat, curret_lon = None, None

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)

m = ax1.pcolormesh(mlon, mlat, value_1)
fig.colorbar(m, ax=ax1)
fig.tight_layout()


def on_move(event):
    global current_lat, current_lon
    if event.inaxes is ax1:
        event_lat = floor(event.ydata)
        event_lon = floor(event.xdata)
        # find the indices corresponding to lat,lon
        id_lat = np.searchsorted(lat, event_lat)
        id_lon = np.searchsorted(lon, event_lon)

        # only plot if we have different values than the previous plot
        if id_lat != current_lat or id_lon != current_lon:
            current_lat = id_lat
            current_lon = id_lon
            ax2.cla()
            ax2.plot(value_2[id_lat, id_lon, :], pressure)
            ax2.set_title("lat: {:.0f}, lon: {:.0f}".format(event_lat, event_lon))
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works! But, **1.** if the length of `lon` and `lat` are both `3000`. It will be slower. **2.** When zooming in, the profile won't change anymore.

Comment: To make it somewhat faster, you could replace the ["motion_notify_event" by a "button_release_event"](https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html), that way the calculations are only performed when you click, instead of everytime the mouse moves. About the zoom, I don't know what you mean. The code still works fine if I zoom in on the top axes on my computer

Comment: Oh, I see .... Because you use `floor` which results in integer, there's no change when mouse moves in the integer . Thank you!

Comment: If lon and lat are irregular decimals, it seems  hard to make it work.

Comment: @Diziet Asahi this is a perfect example of how to handle events. Saving for later.

Comment: This works for irregular lon and lat: `event_lat = event.ydata`
        `event_lon = event.xdata`
        `id_lat = np.where(lat==lat[lat<=event_lat][-1])[0][0]`
        `id_lon = np.where(lon==lon[lon<=event_lon][-1])[0][0]`